# Added hidden element, but now my hover effect doesn't work anymore

Tags: hover, hidden

I have a problem with my javascript code, I made a hover effect for a text to play a video. but now I want to hide the video when you not hover the text. when I'm adding a hidden element, the hover effect does not work anymore...

Do you guys know the solution?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var Htext=document.getElementById("Htext");
var Hvideo=document.getElementById("Hvideo");

function PauseH(){
    Hvideo.pause();
}

function PlayH(){
if(Hvideo.paused)
    Hvideo.play();
    
}

if(Hvideo.pause){
    Hvideo.hidden = true;
}else{
    Hvideo.hidden = false;
}
</script>

<div>
<video id="Hvideo" width="320" height="240" preload="auto">
    <source src="URL will be added" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<button id="Htext" onmouseover="PlayH()" onmouseout="PauseH()">HVAC</button>

</div>
```

Comment: did you mean for the last section to be "paused" instead of "pause"? is that a copy/paste error, or the actual error?

Comment: Hai @jad, also when I'm changed it to paused, the error is still there. i think the 2 codes don't match or something. I'm writing javascript code for a week now, so i really don't know whats going wrong....

Comment: that particular bit of code will be called only when the section of javascript is initially read in.  you'll need to move the "hide" to the play/pause function if you want it to be called during the play/pause action

Comment: @jad that was the same as i thought! but when i added the code to the section, i works when i'm moving my mouse over the text. when i move the mouse away from the text the video disappears. but the problem with this code is, when i move back over the text nothing happens anymore

Comment: can you include the "mouseover" code that you're using?

Comment: @jad i edit the question and added the mouse over code. i want to thank you think along with me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code appears to be essentially working:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GMLBBYWJV4I2

```
<div>

<button id="Htext" onmouseover="PlayH()" onmouseout="PauseH()">HVAC</button>

</div>

<video id="Hvideo" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<script>
var Htext=document.getElementById("Htext");
var Hvideo=document.getElementById("Hvideo");

function PauseH(){
    Hvideo.pause();
    Hvideo.hidden = true;
}

function PlayH(){
  if(Hvideo.paused) {
    Hvideo.play();
    Hvideo.hidden = false;
  }    
}

</script>
```

I do wonder if the issue is down to the fact that you need the HTML elements to exist before you run your JavaScript, and it will fail if the JavaScript runs before the elements appear on the page.

Comment: Dear @jad, thank you so much for replying. I think the problem of this matter is the link thought elementor and the HTML widget.... the guys from elementor examine the problem. I'm kind of relieved the problem does not excist due thought my lack of knowledge :p